# URI has disallowed characters in... IE

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, codeigniter, uri

I have this new problem with IE, it keeps getting this URI disallowed characters error in Internet explorer.

The calls are made through AJAX and it works fine in the **LOCALHOST**, but on the server, it doesn't work at all.

Examples of the url called (sorry, had to xxxx some parts for disclosure issues)

```
http://sandbox.xxxxxxxxx.pt/beta1/gestao/xxxxxxx_ctr/?%23&_=1302607702688 (this one doesn't work in IE)

http://localhost/xxxxxxxxx/gestao/xxxxxxx_ctr/?%23&_=1302608090193 (this one does)
```

These permitted uri chars work like a charm for the "good" browsers.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\+\-';
```

Does anyone happens to know the solution to this problem and would be kind enough to help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this portion: `?%23&` why is the URL encoded `#` there in the first place?

Comment: That's just for anti cache purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

the `?#` was being added because the "cache" option was set to false in the jQuery ajax request, so the IE caching didn't kicked in.

Simply removed the cache preventing option in the AJAX request and added a "random" number to be sent via post, to prevent IE cache.

At least for now it's working fine.

Thank you guys for the time spent trying to help me.